# Autofocus on field when page loads using js on a class instead of input id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a site I would like to use js to set focus to an input field when the page loads.  I am unable to change the following code. Here is the input tag:

```
input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched"
      ng-model="query.q" type="text"
      placeholder="Enter search terms - use quotes for phrases"
      kw-clearable-input=""
```

I have tried js below looking at other similar topics but no luck:

```
function setFocusToTextBox(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched")[0]; element.focus();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check that when you call the function setFocusToTextBox() the html element already has all the classes you are asking for. Did you try logging before the getElementsByClassName inside the function ?

Comment: I've been looking more into solutions still and the input tag is inside of a div tag. I'm fairly new to angularjs which from what I'm seeing is this that I'm working with.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that element is not define in the focus function.

When define correctly, it is working.

```js
function setFocusToTextBox()
{ 
  let element = document
    .getElementsByClassName("form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched")[0]; 
  
  element.focus();
}

setFocusToTextBox();
```

```html
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-model="query.q" type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms - use quotes for phrases" kw-clearable-input=""/>
```

You could also remove element and join the query with focus like this :

```js
function setFocusToTextBox()
{ 
  document.getElementsByClassName("form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched")[0].focus();
}

setFocusToTextBox();
```

```html
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-model="query.q" type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms - use quotes for phrases" kw-clearable-input=""/>
```

Here with the layout provided :

```js
function setFocusToTextBox()
{ 
  document.querySelector( '.input-group.dropdown input' ).focus();
}

setFocusToTextBox();
```

```html
<div class="input-group dropdown" dropdown="" keyboard-nav="" is-open="opt.showFqDropdown"> <span style="position: relative;"> <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-model="query.q" type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms - use quotes for phrases" kw-clearable-input=""/>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both of these solutions but still no luck. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: the input tag is inside this div tag

<div class="input-group dropdown" dropdown="" keyboard-nav="" is-open="opt.showFqDropdown">

 <span style="position: relative;">

<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-model="query.q" type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms - use quotes for phrases" kw-clearable-input="">

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autofocus`

```html
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng- 
 model="query.q"
 type="text"
 placeholder="Enter search terms - use quotes for phrases"
 kw-clearable-input="" 
 autofocus>
```

Comment: I'm not able to add the autofocus to the input tag. Since I cannot change the current code.